# Doxygen 1.8.18 - Nested structure link generation

Tags: c, doxygen

I am using doxygen 1.8.18 and want to have a link in html generated documentation for a variable within a nested stucture. I'm trying to make a link for the following scenario:

```
typdef struct{

ui8 var;

} Struct2_ts;
```

```
typdef struct{

Struct2_ts Struct2;

} Struct1_ts;
```

Creating link for the variable and the structure where it is defined is functional:

```
#Struct2_ts.var //this works
```

However my goal is to create a link for the variable in nested structure:

```
#Struct1_ts.Struct2_ts.var  //not working
#Struct1_ts.Struct2.var     //not working
```

Is this supported or am I just doing it wrong?

All the files where stuctures are defined are included by doxyfile configuration. Is there another setting which affects this in doxyfile?

Tried going through https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/autolink.html and creating the link in a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1.8.18 version is already a bit older, the current version is 1.9.5 (so advise is, independent of the problem, an update would not hurt).

I'm not 100% sure what you would like to see but I imagine it is one of the links as show here:

[image]

I used for this the following source code:

```
/// \file
///
/// nested \ref Struct2_ts.var "Struct1_ts.Struct2_ts.var"
///
/// nested \ref Struct2_ts.var "Struct1_ts.Struct2.var"

typdef struct Struct2_ts {

ui8 var;

} Struct2_ts;

typdef struct{

Struct2_ts Struct2;

} Struct1_ts;
```

and the settings:

```
QUIET = YES
EXTRACT_ALL = YES
```

Doxygen does not, always, follow the variables as shown, so the auto linking is not always working for the nested cases. You should also use a named struct and not an anonymous struct
With the `\ref` command one can specify where the links points to and what the text  is that should be shown in a hyperlink.

Comment: Hi Albert, 
yes, this is exactly what I meant.

Today I found out that also #Struct1_ts.Struct2_ts.var option works if Struct2 is named and Struct1 is anonymous in version 1.9.5 (not in 1.8.18). Anyways your approach is the way to go. Since the structs are also documented EXTRACT_ALL = YES isn't necessary. Thank you